# asp.net MVC - cannot understand why routing is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web API project, I have the following routing defined in `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
            );
```

I have a controller called `UserFeedController` with an action with the following signature:

```
public UserFeedResponseViewModel GetUserFeed(int id)
```

When I enter the url `http://api.mydomain.com/UserFeed/GetUserFeed/4` I get a 404. Why doesn't the second routing rule apply?

MVC routing is quite beyond my power to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two routes are basically the same.  MVC finds the first route that matches and since you have specified a controller and an action, it thinks you are good to go.  It will ignore the id that you specified (I believe it might try to pass it in as a parameter).

I would suggest changing your first route to include API/ at the beginning like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "DefaultApi", 
            routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{action}" 
        ); 

        routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "Default", 
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" 
        );
```

That will insure that your routes work properly.

Comment: My God! I didn't notice until now that the code calls two separate methods: `MapRoute()` and `MapHttpRoute()`. Why on earth is routing done differently for Web API controllers?! I have changed the code to always use `MapHttpRoute()` and now I'm getting behaviour I expect...